# TYPO3 Extbase sort foreign Model (1:n)

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

I got a `Seminar` and an `Event` model. The Seminars have a `1:n` relation with the Events.
Now when I select all Seminars with `$this->seminarRepository->findAll()`, I want the Seminars sorted by `start_date`.

I tried changing the TCAs `foreign_sortby` and `foreign_default_sortby`, I also tried adding the sorting directly into the given repository `$query->setOrderings(['events.start_date' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING]);`. None of this did work.

**Seminar Model**

```php
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Myext\Domain\Model;

    use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity;

    class Seminar extends AbstractEntity
    {
        /**
         * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Vendor\Myext\Domain\Model\Event>
         */
        protected $events;
```

**Seminar TCA**

```php
'events'           => [
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label'   => 'Veranstaltungen',
    'config'  => [
            'type'                => 'inline',
            'foreign_table'       => 'tx_myext_domain_model_event',
            'foreign_field'       => 'seminar',
            'foreign_default_sortby'      => 'ORDER BY tx_myext_domain_model_event.start_date ASC',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems that `foreign_default_sortby` was not implemented for extbase yet: https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/61487

Since my first solution did not work properly (see comments for details), I am now sorting the array of events via PHP `usort`:

```php
usort($events, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a->getStartDate() == $b->getStartDate()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->getStartDate() > $b->getStartDate()) ? +1 : -1;
});
```

---

#### Old no working answer

My **temporary** solution is to use `foreign_sortby`, but only for the frontend, since `foreign_default_sortby` works fine in the backend.

**Seminar TCA**

```php
$seminarTca = [

    // More TCA stuff; missing some array keys in this code

    'events'           => [
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label'   => 'Veranstaltungen',
            'config'  => [
                    'type'                   => 'inline',
                    'foreign_table'          => 'tx_myext_domain_model_event',
                    'foreign_field'          => 'seminar',
                    'foreign_default_sortby' => 'start_date',
                    'maxitems'               => 999,
                    'appearance'             => [
                            'collapseAll'           => true,
                            'expandSingle'          => true,
                            'newRecordLinkAddTitle' => true,
                            'levelLinksPosition'    => 'both',
                            'useSortable '          => false,
                    ],
            ],
    ],
];

if (TYPO3_MODE === 'FE') {
    $seminarTca['columns']['events']['config']['foreign_sortby'] = 'start_date';
}

return $seminarTca;
```

Comment: This won't work since TCA is built once and then cached. Also notice that `foreign_sortby` is very different from `foreign_default_sortby` and can cause data loss in case foreign records are reordered.

Comment: About the caching I am not sure. I will double check this. In know the difference, that's why I only use `foreign_sortby` in the frontend, where the events cannot be sorted by the user.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds like this is not possible, not even in pure SQL since you cannot sort a single row by field values of multiple related rows.

Maybe you want to mirror the closest start date of the related events to your seminar model, then you can simply use this for sorting in your `SeminarRepository`:

```php
protected $defaultOrderings = [
    'nextEventStartDate' => QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING,
];
```

Comment: Well this makes sense. But in the query log I can see that typo3 creates its own query to select the events for each seminar. However my `EventsRepository` gets never called, thus my defined orderings are useless.